# While using Scrollify, I get a Scrollify is not a function error

Tags: jquery, jquery-scrollify

I have added the scrollify.js file locally, but I still get the error `$.scrollify is not a function`.

I tried bower install, but that didn't seem to help.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../static/jquery.scrollify.js"></script>
```

...

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $.scrollify({
          section : ".sectionalScrolling",
      });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Did you implement jquery as well?

Comment: @AliSheikhpour if they didn't the error would be `$ is undefined`

Comment: Are you sure the path to the file is correct? Check the console to ensure the file is loaded properly.

Comment: Yep, I've imported jquery- `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Yep, the file path is correct.

Comment: Here's a similar issue- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40117466/scrollify-function-not-being-found-even-when-script-is-imported

Comment: Also make sure that the usage of script is after the implementation line.

Comment: Yes, as shown in the code snippet, I’m using it after I import it.